# Spring cloud with ribbon not ignoring down servers

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I was followig spring guide on client side load balancing with eureka:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/

But I'm getting a connection refuse exception when after having 3 server instances I shut down any of them. Instead of the ignoring the servers that fail the ping, the client is still trying to send requests to those servers. I get an exception when those servers are pinged and the same exception when I the client tries to send requests to those servers. It seems like the ribbon is performing some sort of blind round-robbin through all servers listed in the configurations and it is ignoring the servers that I shut down.

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: user

server:
  port: 8888

say-hello:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8090,localhost:9092,localhost:9999
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
```

SayHelloConfiguration.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IPing;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.PingUrl;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule;

public class SayHelloConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig;

    @Bean
    public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
        return new PingUrl();
    }

    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }

}
```

UserApplication.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RibbonClient(name = "say-hello", configuration = SayHelloConfiguration.class)
public class UserApplication {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public String hi(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="Artaban") String name) {
        String greeting = this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://say-hello/greeting", String.class);
        return String.format("%s, %s!", greeting, name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>user</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>user</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

This is the exception I'm getting when pinging the down servers:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.PingUrl.isAlive(PingUrl.java:126)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer$SerialPingStrategy.pingServers(BaseLoadBalancer.java:927)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer$Pinger.runPinger(BaseLoadBalancer.java:676)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer$PingTask.run(BaseLoadBalancer.java:629)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

This is the exception I'm getting when the client app sends requests to the down servers:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerRequestFactory$1.apply(LoadBalancerRequestFactory.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerRequestFactory$1.apply(LoadBalancerRequestFactory.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286) ~[spring-retry-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:163) ~[spring-retry-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:86) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at hello.UserApplication.hi(UserApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

What am I missing? The expected behaviour would be that after the ping fails to the servers shut down, the client app would ignore those servers and sent no more requests to them.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using eureka to register the sevices? If yes are the service instances still showing in the eureka web interface after you shut them down?

Comment: I'm not using eureka, no. As you can see in the client's application.yml, I'm using a static list of servers to connect to, the idea of this tutorial is just to understand load balancing in spring cloud. Do you think this static list of servers is a problem? Considering that when I shut down any of those servers the client continue to ping it and to send requests to it.

Comment: how long are you waiting after you shut down the servers?

Comment: I configured ping to contact active servers every 15 seconds. After I shut a server down, the next ping will throw the exception above and when I perform the request in the client app and the "round robin" gets to that server that I shut down, the other exception is thrown. I'm not waiting any particular time to perform requests after shuting down the server but I've tried to do it only after the ping fails and the behaviour persists.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I came across this problem and here is how I tried to solve it. Not sure if this is the ideal way to go, but this seems sufficient for my needs right now.

The IPing implementation only helps determine if the server is alive or dead. It does not remove the server from the list of available servers.

As per the [Javadoc here](https://netflix.github.io/ribbon/ribbon-core-javadoc/com/netflix/loadbalancer/BaseLoadBalancer.html#markServerDown(com.netflix.loadbalancer.Server)), looks like Ribbon leaves that the decision to client on when to mark a server as unhealthy. It seems a safe choice. Should the server be marked unavailable if it fails 1 ping vs. 3 pings and should there be a backoff while pinging - all this would be dependent on the kind of application you have at hand, so it is only the client that can make a safe choice.

However, there is no clear indication as to how to add a ServerStatusChangeListener to the load balancer in the context of Spring Cloud Netflix. So, I think if we had that ability, that would be the right place to call the `BaseLoadBalancer.markServerDown(Server)` from within the listener. Spring Cloud guru's (@spencergibb) can weigh in here.

Moving on to how I implemented my solution. In addition to the IPing, I have also configured a IRule and extended my rule from the `com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule`. Since this rule filters the servers that are circuit tripped, the only thing you would have to be adding is a check if the server itself is alive or not before return it as the chosen server.

```
@Configuration
public class MyLoadBalancerConfig {

    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new AvailabilityBasedServerSelectionRule();
    }

    @Bean
    public IPing ribbonPing() {
        return server -> {
            try {
                // TODO: ping your server to decide if health check has passed or not
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList(IClientConfig config) {
        return new ServerList<Server>() {
            @Override
            public List<Server> getInitialListOfServers() {
                Server server1 = new Server("server1");
                Server server2 = new Server("server2");
                return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(server1, server2));
            }

            @Override
            public List<Server> getUpdatedListOfServers() {
                Server server3 = new Server("server3");
                Server server4 = new Server("server4");

                return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(server3, server4));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and

```
public class AvailabilityBasedServerSelectionRule extends AvailabilityFilteringRule {

    @Override
    public Server choose(Object key) {

        Server chosenServer = super.choose(key);

        int count = 1;
        List<Server> reachableServers = this.getLoadBalancer().getReachableServers();
        List<Server> allServers = this.getLoadBalancer().getAllServers();

        if(reachableServers.size() > 0) {
            while(!reachableServers.contains(chosenServer) && count++ < allServers.size()) {
                chosenServer = super.choose(key);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("chosenServer.isAlive() = " + chosenServer.isAlive());
        return chosenServer;
    }
}
```

Thus, the AvailabilityBasedServerSelectionRule always returns servers that are alive and NOT circuit tripped. I am yet to find any issues with this solution approach. I will update this post, if I find any as I go forward with this approach. Good luck!

Comment: choose method is getting called each time , but how it came to know about non reachable server ?  this.getLoadBalancer().getReachableServers(); is it guarantee to return only availble server. I have implemented your solution but still it sends request to one of downed server.

Comment: It has been more than 2 years since this answer and I forgot most part of the problem :).. However, in my solution above - there is a TODO in `public IPing ribbonPing()` method of the MyLoadBalancerConfig.java class. I am thinking you need to implement that health check to figure out whether your server is healthy and return response accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell ribbon to retry next server if it is not there:

```
say-hello:
  ribbon:
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1
```

This also works when using eureka. Since service registry removes servers delayed if they not crash and not deregister.

Additionally, you need to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the tutorial, this is a simplified example:

> Load balancers in Ribbon normally get their server lists from a
>   Netflix Eureka service registry... for our simple purposes here, we’re skipping Eureka

Your application cannot know that your server is no longer available. This is the job of a service registry (for instance eureka) that can handle the job of discovering which services are dead or alive via heartbeat mechanisms...

Comment: So having a static list of servers, the client app will always try to send requests to all of them even though ping fails? What is the purpose of pinging those servers that are in the static list then?

Comment: Its just a very simplified scenario given in the tutorial to demonstrate how ribbon load balancing works. Ribbon by default just does a round robbin load balancing. If you want something more robust you should use eureka as demonstrated in this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Answer (score 1):

After debugging BaseLoadBalancer I realized the following thing: 
Ribbon pings all sever instances from the list and determines which of them are dead. Ribbon does it in SerialPingStrategy, which is default implementation of IPingStrategy. These ping results are processed and the list of servers which status has changed since last ping process are send to ServerStatusChangeListener instances if at least some of them exist. But there is no any implementation provided in given tutorial. I suppose that if you provide some implementation of ServerStatusChangeListener and add it in application context, then there may be different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

PingUrl try to resolve if the servers are lived, for all the servers that you indicate in the property listOfServers:
`localhost:8090`,`localhost:9092`,`localhost:9999`
so you must start all the services or remove the services that you don't need

That's all folks!